# How can i make http requests via selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, python-requests, request

Im using selenium in python to automate websites, and on one of my websites on foot size pick i noticed there is no < button > element i can click on and that i have to make 'GET' request to the site to pick the size, and how can i make it so i still can see what happens in selenium ex. i use request to pick size and then selenium to add to cart. Here is the element on the site

```
<a href="https://www.snipes.pl/p/jordan-air_jordan_1_zoom_air_comfort-dark_iris%2Fwhite%2Fblack%2Fsail-00013802067771.html" class="js-pdp-attribute-btn b-pdp-swatch-link js-pdp-attribute-btn--size" data-attr-id="size" data-value="44" data-variant-id="0001380206777100000006" data-href="/p/jordan-air_jordan_1_zoom_air_comfort-dark_iris%2Fwhite%2Fblack%2Fsail-00013802067771.html?chosen=size&amp;dwvar_00013802067771_size=44">
<span data-attr-value="44" class="js-pdp-attribute-tile b-size-value js-size-value b-swatch-circle b-swatch-value b-swatch-value--selectable b-swatch-value--orderable">44</span>
</a>
```

so i think i need to make a GET request to `https://www.snipes.pl/p/jordan-air_jordan_1_zoom_air_comfort-dark_iris%2Fwhite%2Fblack%2Fsail-00013802067771.html?chosen=size&amp;dwvar_00013802067771_size=44`

Thank you very much

Comment: So does making a get request to that url adds the item to the cart? If yes, you can do get url for that link and then switch back to your previous context

Comment: No, it just selects the size. Then you make other request to add to cart @Himanshuman

Comment: can you share url of the page

Comment: @Himanshuman https://www.snipes.pl/p/jordan-air_jordan_1_zoom_air_comfort-dark_iris%2Fwhite%2Fblack%2Fsail-00013802067771.html here you go:)

Comment: It's `a' tag with a `href` attribute, which implies that it is clickable. You do not necessarily need a button to click. A link is also clickable, and this is a link. Have you tried clicking on  it?

Comment: By the way, I see that the website detects bots

Comment: @AnandGautam Thank you very much, the website has perimeterx bot protection.

Comment: Can you give us the website that you're viewing? Is it that Snipes.PL web URL?

Comment: @ZvjezdanVeselinovic https://www.snipes.pl/p/jordan-air_jordan_1_zoom_air_comfort-dark_iris%2Fwhite%2Fblack%2Fsail-00013802067771.html